# Algorithm for the nilpotence of matrix polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, nilpotent-matrices

Let $P$ be a multivariate polynomial of real-valued $N \times N$ matrices. Given $X_1, X_2, ..., X_M \in \mathcal{M}_N\{\mathbb{R}\}$, is there any optimal algorithm to determine whether the result of $P(X_1, X_2, ..., X_M)$ is nilpotent?

Comment: How about binary exponentiation? Are you expecting an answer that doesn’t just use an algorithm that checks whether a matrix is nilpotent?

Comment: I'm looking for anything that behaves better than the straight-forward computation of the polynomial. Preferably something involving as few matrix multiplications as possible (even fewer than what binary exponentiation uses). I am unsure if such an algorithm exists.